# PHP SSH Commands Using phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I am using http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ to connect to my SSH and run some commands for my node server.

Its working perfectly using:

```
echo "Restart...<br>";
echo "<pre>";
echo $ssh->exec('forever restartall');
echo "</pre>";
```

However, as soon as I use the following code it doesn't display anything or run anything:

```
echo "Starting...<br>";
echo "<pre>";
echo $ssh->exec('cd /var/www/html/game-api');
echo $ssh->exec('forever start server.js > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt &');
echo "</pre>";
```

The command works perfectly if I run it direct from the terminal.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir,

> ```
> echo $ssh->exec('pwd'); // outputs /home/username
> $ssh->exec('cd /');
> echo $ssh->exec('pwd'); // (despite the previous command) outputs /home/username
> ```
>
> **Successive calls to exec()**
>
> If done on an interactive shell, the output you'd receive for the
>   first pwd would (depending on how your system is setup) be different
>   than the output of the second pwd. The above code snippet, however,
>   will yield two identical lines.
>
> The reason for this is that any "state changes" you make to the
>   one-time shell are gone once the exec() has been ran and the channel
>   has been deleted.
>
> You can workaround this on Linux by doing `$ssh->exec('cd /; pwd')`